# Display data from database using selected value from combo list.. (ASP)

Tags: asp-classic

Does anyone know how to retrieve and display data from database using combo list? What I mean is this..I have a form..in the form there is a combo list and two textfiels..the user need to choose their company using that combo list..once they have chose their company, the address and contact number of the company will be display in the next two textfields called CAddress and CContact..for example, if the user chose company ABC..how can I display the company ABC address and contact number in those textfields? Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you could use javascript and make a call ajax to an asp page passing the id of the company ... in that page you can jsut response.write  the infos u need as a xml format ... even csv format would work ... then jsut take the response and write it in the textbox